# How to get data from dynamically generated JavaFX PieChart?

Tags: java, javafx, graph

I'm trying to figure out how to get and update existing data in a set of dynamically created pie charts in JavaFX. These pie charts are all saved in an `ArrayList`. The first task is figure out how to get that data.

As I'm creating these pie charts dynamically from a set of fluid data sources, I cannot make multiple observable lists using code similar to this:

```
private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Any ideas on how can I read the data name and value from each dynamically generated pie chart slice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflow's content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Why not modify a single `ObservableList` for each chart?

Comment: that would be an idea if the number of charts was fixed, however the actual number of charts can vary based on the amount of information. Or are you suggesting linking a observablelist to each chart dynamically? I'm not sure how that could be done on the fly.

Comment: I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `PieChart` (view) has access to its own `ObservableList<PieChart.Data>` (model) via its `data` property. Given a `List<PieChart>` named `list`, you can traverse the list and examine or update each chart's data as warranted:

```
list.get(0).getData().get(0).setPieValue(42);
for (PieChart p : list) {
    for (PieChart.Data data : p.getData()) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Console data from Ensemble8 [`PieChartApp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/86b854dc367fb32743810716da5583f7d59208f8/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/charts/pie/chart/PieChartApp.java):

```
Data[Sun,42.0]
Data[IBM,12.0]
Data[HP,25.0]
Data[Dell,22.0]
Data[Apple,30.0]
```

As an alternative to having a list of views, `List<PieChart>`, consider maintaining a list of models, `List<ObservableList<PieChart.Data>>`.